# Collectors.toMap() does not behave as intended when mapping between an array and a rotated copy of said array

Tags: java

I have an array `splitAlphabet` and a rotated copy of said array `shiftedAlphabet`:

```
static String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

String[] splitAlphabet = ALPHABET.split("(?!^)");

List<String> shiftedAlphabetList = Arrays.asList(splitAlphabet); 
Collections.rotate(shiftedAlphabetList, -4);

String[] shiftedAlphabet = shiftedAlphabetList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Example:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD
```

I try to create a map where the keys would be the values from `splitAlphabet` and the values would be from `shiftedAlphabet`:

```
A -> E
B -> F
C -> G
...
```

Here is the code snippet I wrote for said map creation:

```
IntStream.range(0, splitAlphabet.length)
         .boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(index -> splitAlphabet[index], 
                                   index -> shiftedAlphabet[index]));
```

The issue is that instead of the expected result, I get this:

```
A -> A
B -> B
C -> C
...
```

Can anyone enlighten me on where I went wrong? or am I understanding `Collectors.toMap()` incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(splitAlphabet)` creates a List object which is backed by the `splitAlphabet` array (as described in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))).  When you modify that List, you modify the array which backs it.

Solution:  Create a new, independent List, which is not backed by that array:

```
List<String> shiftedAlphabetList = new ArrayList<>(
    Arrays.asList(splitAlphabet));
```